# Find out Ok in JOptionPane InputDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

This is my input dialog:

[image]

But my code can't recognize selected buttons correctly:

(No message appear on console at all)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int userId = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter User ID", "").trim());

    if (userId == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("ok selected");
    } else if (userId == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("Cancel selected");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html is a good starting place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of showInputDialog returns you the value you enter in the inputbox. So comparing it with ok or cancel option does not make sense.

There goes your new code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter User ID", "");
if(result == null) {
 System.out.println("cancel selected");
return;

}
            int userId = Integer.parseInt(result.trim());
        System.out.println("user id is:" + userId );


}
```

Comment: So how can i find out which button is selected by user in `InputDialog`?

Comment: JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter User ID", "") will return null if you click on cancel. If you click on ok you'll get a result. An empty string even if you don't enter anything

Comment: Now i can't compare something like this : `if (userId != null)` , how detect result is not null?